# How to prevent re-initializing pthread_rwlock_t

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm declaring array of pthread_rwlock_t static global.
e.g. static pthread_rwlock_t cm[255];
Inside constructor I want to initialize one of the 255 mutex( I keep track with static counter)

Now I'm confused with
1) I don't want to re-initialize lock again, that is bad!
I thought reinitialize should return some error code, but it doesn't:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_rwlock_t cm[2];

int main()
{
    int ret;
    ret = pthread_rwlock_init(&cm[0], NULL);
    ret = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&cm[0]);
    printf("Ret: %d\n", ret);

    ret =  pthread_rwlock_init(&cm[0], NULL);
    printf("Ret: %d\n", ret);

    ret = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&cm[0]);
    printf("Ret: %d\n", ret);
}
```

Result:

```
Ret: 0
Ret: 0
Ret: 0
```

Can anyone help, 1) If this is possible, then how? 2) If not what should be alternative approach?

EDIT 1:
I'm updating from comments/answers I got:

> > > Instead, just put the rwlocks inside the objects they protect. 
> > >       So I have n # of objects getting called, and will be using that many pthread_lock .. so disadvantage is memory. Hence I'm trying to improve on that part with global array of locks. Picking 256 to get good distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need static initialization, use PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER on your array.

```
static pthread_rwlock_t cm[2] = { PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER , 
                                  PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER} ;
```

This is equivalent as calling pthread_rwlock_init() on every element with attr parameter specified as NULL, except that no error checking is performed.

Comment: at least for now my use cases pthread_once or initializing in main isn't an option.

Comment: For my use case, those two suggestion aren't useful: neither pthread_once nor initializing in main.

Comment: @codemuncher You should update the question then, if you can't use dynamic initialization.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior to call `pthread_rwlock_init` (or analogously any of the pthread primitive init functions) more than once on the same object, and logically there's no way it would make sense to do so anyway since (as you've demonstrated) the object is already in use. You said in the comments on 2501's answer that you can't use `pthread_once`, but this makes no sense. If you're able to call `pthread_rwlock_init`, you can instead just call `pthread_once` using an init function which performs the call to `pthread_rwlock_init`.

However I really think you're experiencing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is no sense in maintaining a "global pool" of rwlocks and handing them out dynamically in constructors. Instead, just put the rwlocks inside the objects they protect. If you really want to hand them out from a global pool like you're doing, you need to keep track of which ones have been handed out *independently* of the job of initializing them, and have the task of initializing them after obtaining one, and destroying one before giving it back to the pool, be handled by the constructor/destructor for the object using them.

Comment: >>>Instead, just put the rwlocks inside the objects they protect. Ans: So I have n # of objects getting called, and will be using that many pthread_lock .. so disadvantage is memory (I can have 10K of objects!!). Hence trying to improve on that part with global array of locks. Just pick a # 255, to have good distribution.

Comment: 10k is way too small to be doing bad hacks like this. The overhead for 10k rwlocks is probably about 320k of memory. Not significant unless you're working with really tiny systems. If you *really* do need to do this, though, you just need synchronization to track that initialization of each rwlock happens exactly once before it gets used. The easiest way would be to initialize them all at once using `pthread_once` and a single `pthread_once_t` object.

Comment: well it is way more than 10K, and I want to try! I'll try with pthread_once